# Adding Service Reference for a Web Reference

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap, windows-phone-7

I've started working on Windows Phone 7 and came across this problem.

I have a VS 08 console application that has a Web reference added to it and every thing works great, I have previously worked with Service Reference in WP7 and used the proxy classes.

I am not good in server side stuff and am not sure about the difference between Web and Service References i think Service refernce is for WCF only and Web supports SOAP as well, Any ways now i need to use that web Reference which is using SOAP Protocol in WP7 but when i add it as Service reference it doesn't show all proxy classes in object explorer.

Wasted 2 days in googling this and still I am not sure where to start. kindly Let me know if you have any questions.

Please HELP !

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the web reference and coding for it will be similar to coding in your console app.

The main differences will be that WP7 requires you to use Asynchronous coding - i.e. instead of calling the service like a normal method, instead you have to pass in an event handler for when the web service call returns.

A partial tutorial is available within this article -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff872395.aspx - start at "Figure 6 Adding a SOAP Service Reference"

There are also some additional limitations in the WP7 implementation - e.g. it's harder to send certain things like soap headers - but hopefully your SOAP service will work OK.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply Stuart, I have used Async calls so i understand what you are trying to say, I have added the Service reference the way it is shown in figure 6 (without adding the code) the thing is Proxy classes generated are incomplete! Some are there others are not, however service reference is included. what do you say on this? Is it because other functions may have been using Syn calls thats why they are being excluded ? Thanks

Comment: I think you need to explain more... which methods exactly are there and which are missing? It might help if you can point us to the .asmx reference on the web - or if you can show specifics about what is there and what is missing.

Comment: This is the reference: https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2010_2_0/netsuite.wsdl

Comment: For instance:  Class NetSuiteService is missing in Service Reference but is available in Web Refernce.